# Godaddy Wildcard Cert and Missing Private Key

Tags: ssl-certificate, windows-server

A wildcard certificate from Godaddy was recently purchased by my organization. While walking through the steps on the Godaddy's site to setup the cert, I typed in the domain name instead of uploading a CSR. Fast forward, this will be for Windows servers and I downloaded the certificate bundle.  I see one PEM file and two CRT files. In short, the PEM file is really a Certificate and not the private key. Since I did not upload a CSR and let Godaddy do this, how do I get the private key?